# Strike through any item in a list created using material ui and Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, strikethrough

I am trying to strike through a list item once a user has clicked on that particular item.

I have created a function to conduct the style change

```
const completed = () =>{
     return document.getElementById("demo").style.textDecoration='line-through'
};
```

The list is generated as below, i have used material ui library

```
 <List dense={dense} >
      {items.slice(0).reverse().map(x=> (
           <ListItem key={x.id} button id="demo" onClick={completed} divider>
                 <ListItemText primary={listItems(x)}/>
                 <ListItemSecondaryAction />
           </ListItem>

       ))}                              
</List>
```

From the code i have written i am able to strike only through the first item of the list. Whenever i add new items , always the only item i am able to strike through is the first item.

I am trying to find a way to apply this to all the elements on the list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not a good practice to use `document.getElementById()` in React because then you are accessing the DOM directly. Instead, you have to use `ref`.

From official [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

> When to Use Refs  There are a few good use cases for refs:
>
> - Managing focus, text selection, or media playback.
> - Triggering imperative animations.
> - Integrating with third-party DOM libraries.

**But in your case** we can easily do this by using React `state`. I assume that your `items` is stored in your component `state` and in a todo item, you need to store whether it is completed or not ( a boolean value ). You can update the code like the following.

```
const completed = (id) => {
   /* update the state by changing the completed value of the
      clicked todo item */
   this.setState({
      items : this.state.items.map(item => {
         if(item.id === id){
            item.completed = true;
         }
         return item;
      })
   })

}

<List dense={dense}>
  {this.state.items
    .reverse()
    .map(x => (
      <ListItem
        key={x.id}
        button
        // add a unique id
        id={x.id}
        
        // add a strike style depending on the completed property of the todo item
        style={{ textDecoration : x.completed ? 'line-through' : 'none' }} 
        
        // call completed with the id
        onClick={() => completed(x.id)} 

        divider
      >
        <ListItemText primary={listItems(x)} />
        <ListItemSecondaryAction></ListItemSecondaryAction>
      </ListItem>
    ))}
</List>
```

Comment: Hey, If one of the given answers solved your problem please mark it as the answer.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Accepting the other answer instead of this is misleading.

Answer (score 2):

Id's should be all unique in HTML. You should add dynamic id-values to each element and send the id in function-call like following.

```
const completed = (id) => {
 document.getElementById(id).style.textDecoration='line-through'
}

<List dense={dense}>
  {items
    .slice(0)
    .reverse()
    .map(x => (
      <ListItem
        key={x.id}
        button
        id={x.id} // Add dynamic ID
        onClick={() => completed(x.id)} // Send ID to function
        divider
      >
        <ListItemText primary={listItems(x)} />
        <ListItemSecondaryAction></ListItemSecondaryAction>
      </ListItem>
    ))}
</List>
```

Comment: This is not the right answer for a React project. it Should be listed under how not to do it.